# Elasticsearch NEST client with nested aggregations

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, f#, aggregation, nest

I am using NEST 2.3.2. And I am trying to build a query with nested aggregations. Basically, I have an index with logs, which have a timestamp and a result code. I want to first put those logs into buckets of minutes, and then further classify them according to result code.

I have the following F# code for generating the query.

```
/// Generate an aggregation to put buckets by result code
let generateAggregationByResultCode () =
    let resultAggregationName = "result_aggregation"
    let aggregationByResults = new TermsAggregation(resultAggregationName)
    aggregationByResults.Field <- new Field(Name = "Result")
    aggregationByResults.ExecutionHint <- new Nullable<TermsAggregationExecutionHint>(TermsAggregationExecutionHint.GlobalOrdinals);
    aggregationByResults.MinimumDocumentCount <- new Nullable<int>(0);
    aggregationByResults.Size <- new Nullable<int>(bucketSize);
    aggregationByResults.Missing <- "-128"
    aggregationByResults

/// Generate an aggregation to classify into buckets by minutes and then by result code
let generateNewDateHistogramByMinute () =
    let dateHistogramByMinute = new DateHistogramAggregation("by_minute")
    dateHistogramByMinute.Field <- new Field(Name = "OperationTime")
    dateHistogramByMinute.Interval <- new Union<DateInterval, Time>(DateInterval.Minute) // can also use TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0)
    dateHistogramByMinute.MinimumDocumentCount <- new Nullable<int>(0)
    dateHistogramByMinute.Format <- "strict_date_hour_minute"
    let innerAggregations = new AggregationDictionary()
    innerAggregations.[resultInnerAggregationName] <- new AggregationContainer(Terms = generateAggregationByResultCode ())
    dateHistogramByMinute.Aggregations <- innerAggregations
    dateHistogramByMinute
```

I use this aggregation to set the request by

```
let dateHistogram = generateNewDateHistogramByMinute ()
let aggregations = new AggregationDictionary()
aggregations.[histogramName] <- new AggregationContainer(DateHistogram = dateHistogram)
(* ... code omitted ... *)
dslRequest.Aggregations <- aggregations
```

When I print out the request, the aggregation part is like this

```
"aggs": {
    "BucketsByMinutes": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "OperationTime",
        "interval": "minute",
        "format": "strict_date_hour_minute",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      }
    }
  }
```

The inner aggregation is completely lost. Does anyone know how should I construct a request properly? And how do I retrieve that inner buckets when the response is returned? I didn't find appropriate properties or methods for that, and the documentation is basically non-existent.

Comment: Did you see the 2.x documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html ?

Comment: @RussCam I came across that while I was searching for solutions, but it didn't help much. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're not seeing the inner aggregation on the request; I'm seeing it with the following, slightly modified version of what you have

```
open Nest
open Elasticsearch.Net

type Document () =
    member val Name = "" with get, set

let pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
let settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, new InMemoryConnection())

settings.DisableDirectStreaming()
        .PrettyJson()
        .OnRequestCompleted(fun response ->
            if (response.RequestBodyInBytes <> null)
            then
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} \n{2}\n", response.HttpMethod, response.Uri, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestBodyInBytes));
            else Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} \n", response.HttpMethod, response.Uri);

            if (response.ResponseBodyInBytes <> null)
            then
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}\n{1}\n{2}\n", response.HttpStatusCode, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseBodyInBytes), new String('-', 30));
            else Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}\n{1}\n", response.HttpStatusCode, new String('-', 30));
        ) |> ignore

let client = new ElasticClient(settings)

/// Generate an aggregation to put buckets by result code
let generateAggregationByResultCode () =
    let bucketSize = 10
    let resultAggregationName = "result_aggregation"
    let aggregationByResults = new TermsAggregation(resultAggregationName)
    aggregationByResults.Field <- Field.op_Implicit("Result")
    aggregationByResults.ExecutionHint <- new Nullable<TermsAggregationExecutionHint>(TermsAggregationExecutionHint.GlobalOrdinals);
    aggregationByResults.MinimumDocumentCount <- new Nullable<int>(0);
    aggregationByResults.Size <- new Nullable<int>(bucketSize);
    aggregationByResults.Missing <- "-128"
    aggregationByResults

/// Generate an aggregation to classify into buckets by minutes and then by result code
let generateNewDateHistogramByMinute () =
    let dateHistogramByMinute = new DateHistogramAggregation("by_minute")
    dateHistogramByMinute.Field <- Field.op_Implicit("OperationTime")
    dateHistogramByMinute.Interval <- new Union<DateInterval, Time>(DateInterval.Minute) // can also use TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0)
    dateHistogramByMinute.MinimumDocumentCount <- new Nullable<int>(0)
    dateHistogramByMinute.Format <- "strict_date_hour_minute"
    dateHistogramByMinute.Aggregations <- AggregationDictionary.op_Implicit(generateAggregationByResultCode())
    dateHistogramByMinute

let request = new SearchRequest<Document>()
request.Aggregations <- (AggregationDictionary.op_Implicit(generateNewDateHistogramByMinute()))

let response = client.Search<Document>(request)
```

this yields the following in the console

```
POST http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true 
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_minute": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "OperationTime",
        "interval": "minute",
        "format": "strict_date_hour_minute",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "result_aggregation": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Result",
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "execution_hint": "global_ordinals",
            "missing": "-128"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Status: 200
------------------------------
```

The above may be useful while you're developing; when you're ready to execute against Elasticsearch, remove the `InMemoryConnection` from the `ConnectionSettings` constructor and also remove the calls to `.DisableDirectStreaming()`, `.PrettyJson()` and `.OnRequestCompleted(fun)` on `ConnectionSettings`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just replaced `aggregations.[histogramName] <- new AggregationContainer()` with `request.Aggregations <- (AggregationDictionary.op_Implicit(some_aggregation))` and it works. Apparently it's wrong use try to add the aggregation to the `AggregationDictionary` yourself. I just assumed that it functions like a normal dictionary with key-item values and was unaware of the implicit cast.

Comment: indexing into the `AggregationDictionary` should also work as you had it (just tried it), but going that route is a bit more cumbersome as you need to index the aggregation against the name that you provide it; the implicit conversion does this for you

Comment: I don't know why but replacing the two lines works. And now I have troubles getting the inner buckets from the response. I can see them if I print the response in plain text, but I don't know how to access it programmatically. I have `"aggregations": {"BucketsByMinutes": {"items": [{ ..."aggregations": {"result_aggregation": {"items": [{"key": "2003", "docCount": 4},...]}}}]}}` Thanks.

Comment: OK. I figured out how to do it. I need to first use `bucket.Aggregations.["result_aggregation"]` to get the aggregate and then cast it into `BucketAggregate`.

Comment: You can also use the `.Aggs` _helper_ - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/writing-aggregations.html#aggs-vs-aggregations

Comment: But `DateHistogramBucket` doesn't expose `.Aggs` property. Maybe I missed some extensions. But I am glad it finally works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think one problem is that I used different names for the aggregation and the key in the dictionary.